# To where goes bounce mails, From or Reply-to

Tags: email, sendmail

We are having a system that sends mail on behalf of the user (the user provide his own mail address).

The mails are send via our server and are set up to with our company mail address as `From` (as many of our clients have disallowed third party to send mails withe their address as `From`) and with the users mail address in the `Reply-to`.

Is it true that bounce mails are going to the `Reply-to` address rather than to the "From" address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  bounces will go to the reverse-path address in the SMTP envelope, which is usually (if you did not specify otherwise) the same as the From address supplied in the mail headers. Because you (correctly) use your company address as a reverse-path, bounces will be sent to your company. See [Sender Rewriting Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) for an example how it is possible to send bounces to the original user.

Comment: Thanks, will look at the article should we decide to go that way

Comment: There was once a failed attempt to codify an `Errors-To:` header but I don't think it ever took off.  In the messages you receive, you often see the SMTP reverse path as `Return-Path:` but you cannot set this in the outgoing message; it gets overwritten on delivery, or at the very least ignored.